# How to display array inside another array without them multiplying?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, express

so I have this app where I need to display images uploaded to my MongoDB database. I was able to display them probably but I want to go a little bit further by wrapping around a link to each image displayed. The link will contain an `id` of each image where a user can click on and get more info about the images.

so this is where the problem begins. I have to use another method to display those link wrapper around those images. so whenever I use the array to display the link, the images multiply by 3. In a case where I have 3 images in my database, 6 more will be displayed alongside when I use the array to display the link wrapper.

Let me put more context.

These are the images displayed without the link wrapper:

[image]

This is the code I used to display those 5 images.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {meme.find({}, {}, function (err, result) {            
  if (err) throw err; 
  res.render('pages/index', {
    user: req.user,
    path: result.map(u=> u.imgs),   
    Title: 'The Meme Search Engine - Meme Africa'
  });
 });
});
```

The frontend used for displaying those images.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">         
    <% for(var i=0; i<path.length; i++) { %>
      <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
        <img src='http://localhost:5000/public/Images/<%= path[i] %>' style="height: 150px; width: 150px; line-height: 0px" alt="memes">
      </div>
    <% } %>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Now I want to wrap around link with every image so users can click on them to get more info about each image. This will require another array.

so this is how my code looks like:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  meme.find({}, {}, function (err, result) {            
    if (err) throw err; 

    res.render('pages/index', {
      user: req.user,
      pathi: result.map(i => i.username),
      path: result.map(u=> u.imgs),     
      Title: 'The Meme Search Engine - Meme Africa'
    });
  });
});
```

The frontend code looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">         
    <%  for (var x=0; x<pathi.length; x++) {%>
      <% for(var i=0; i<path.length; i++) { %>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
          <a href="/Images/<%= pathi[x]%>">
            <img src='http://localhost:5000/public/Images/<%= path[x] %>' style="height: 150px; width: 150px; line-height: 0px" alt="memes">  
          </a>
        </div>
      <% } %>
    <%}%>
  </div>  
</div>
```

The result:

[image]

You can see that all the images multiply. Meanwhile, I have just 5 images in my MongoDB database. I think the problem is using an array to display the link wrap. Now am curious what is the best way to do this without my initial results multiplying.

I'm sorry for the long answer because the problem looks kinda complex and I need to provide everything to someone that is interested to help me solve. If you want me to clarify anything don't hesitate to let me know in the comment section.

The stack I'm using: Node/express, ejs as the template and MongoDB.

Thanks.

Comment: What you get from mongodb query, pelase add response also form find query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only use `x` index you need only one loop (and obtain only one iteration of memes):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">           

<%  for (var x=0; x<pathi.length; x++) {%>

            <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
<a href="/Images/<%= pathi[x]%>"> <img src='http://localhost:5000/public/Images/<%= path[x] %>' style="height: 150px; width: 150px; line-height: 0px"  alt="memes">  </a>
</div>

  <% } %>
 <%}%>

</div>  
</div>
```

Or you could pass all information as array of object and read properties from one array.

Comment: How do I pass all information as an array of object and read properties from one array?

Comment: Nvm. The stuff is now working. Your answer helped. Thanks.